# how to automatically annotate point or line at certain xy values in loop

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, annotate

Hi I succeeded creating multiple figures of pressure and temperature, etc from excel data using for in loop and generate multiple png files. I attached the script below

Is it possible to automatically create a line or annotation (red scratches) where the temperature of 230 deg C intersects the temperature line plot (blue dotted line)?

[image: figure]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

path ='F:\Backup\JN\TOR\TOR HLS py.xlsx'
data= pd.ExcelFile(path)

sheets = data.sheet_names
well = ''

for i in sheets:
    well=pd.read_excel(data, sheet_name=i)
    fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,12), constrained_layout='True')
    plt.plot(well['x csg'], well['mdpl csg'], marker='s', linestyle='solid', color='black')
    plt.plot(well['x liner'], well['mdpl liner'], marker='s', linestyle='dotted', color='black')
    plt.plot(well['T'], well['mdpl pt'], marker='o', color='blue', label='Temperature')
    plt.plot(well['P'], well['mdpl pt'], marker='o', color='crimson', label='Pressure')
    for x, txt in enumerate(well['csg']):
        plt.annotate(txt, ((well['x csg']+5)[x], well['mdpl csg'][x]), size=8)
    for y, txt in enumerate(well['liner']):
        plt.annotate(txt, ((well['x liner']+5)[y], well['mdpl liner'][y]), size=8)
    plt.savefig(str(i), dpi=300, transparent='True')
    plt.close(i)
```

Please help, thanks

Comment: you could interpolate the temperature data to find out the y position for  x=230, then you have your coordinate to add whatever you want there - text, annotation, line, bar, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the interpolated yvalues from the x and then annotate that interpolated y values with straight line

```
y230=float(np.interp(xval, well['T'], well['mdpl pt']))
if math.isnan(y230) == False:
    plt.annotate('ToR 230 $^o$C', xy=(200, y230), xytext=(250, (y230-9)), 
    arrowprops=dict(color='green', arrowstyle="-", lw=2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the snippet. I will suggest you to use `shapely` library to calculate intersection between 2 lines. This method also works if the paths do not use the same X-axis values. You will get the point of intersection which you can annotate using loops.
[image: Intersection]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import shapely
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

x = np.linspace(0, 5, 20)
y1 = x**2
y2 = 3*x

za1=[(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y1)]    #points for (x,y) line1
za2=[(i,j) for i,j in zip(x,y2)]    #points for (x,y) line2

line1 = LineString(za1)
line2 = LineString(za2)

intersection = line1.intersection(line2)
intersect_points = [list(p.coords)[0] for p in intersection]
print(intersect_points)
#[(0.0, 0.0), (2.994555353901996, 8.983666061705987)]     point of intersection

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y1, color='lightcoral')
plt.plot(x, y2, color='#4b0082')

for i in intersect_points:
  ax.annotate('x',xy=(i),fontsize=20,color='red')
plt.show()
```

You can check more about `Shapely` here [Shapely](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/)